# Solvability of system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Given $a_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ $(1\leq i \leq n)$, I am trying to find the conditions under which the equations
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}=a_i(x_1,...,x_n) 
$$
$$
f(x_0)=z_0
$$
is solvable by Frobenius theorem.

So far, I defined the vector fields

$$
X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}+a_i(x_1,...,x_n)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
$$

on $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}=\{(x,z) : x\in \mathbb{R}^n, z\in \mathbb{R} \}$. I computed
the Lie bracket $[X_i,X_j]$ to find that the distribution spanned by the $X_i$ is  involutive iff 
$$
\frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j}, \ 1\leq i \leq n, 1 \leq j \leq n,
$$
in which case $[X_i,X_j]=0$. I think this should be the integrability condition and I would like to show that there is a solution $z=f(x)$ if this is satisfied. Frobenius's Theorem produces coordinates $(y_1,...,y_{n+1})$ such that the points that satisfy $y_{n+1}=c$ is an integral manifold. I want to use the Implicit Function Theorem to obtain this solution but this requires that 
$$
\frac{\partial y_{n+1}}{\partial z}(x_0)\neq 0.
$$
This is not apparent to me (if it is true at all).

Comment: Couldn't you use the theory of differential forms instead? See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/985745/8157).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had  $$\frac{\partial y_{n+1}}{\partial z}\Big|_{x_0} = 0,$$ then $\partial/\partial z$ would be tangent to the integral manifold passing through $x_0$. This is impossible because $\partial/\partial z$ is not in the span of your $X_i$.